# Simplifying away imaginary part

Tags: simplifying-expressions, linear-algebra, complex, eigenvalues

I'm solving the following eigensystem, and I get result which looks complex-valued. I expect the result to have 0 imaginary part, can anyone see a way to simplify it away?

```
B = {{17/3, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3}, {1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3}, {1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 1/
    3}, {1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 82/3}};
A = {{5/3, 0, 1/3, 0}, {0, 5/3, 0, 1/3}, {1/3, 0, 10/3, 0}, {0, 1/3, 
    0, 10/3}};
First /@ Eigensystem[{B, A}, 1]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
B = {{17/3, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3}, {1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3}, {1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3}, {1/3, 
    1/3, 1/3, 82/3}};
A = {{5/3, 0, 1/3, 0}, {0, 5/3, 0, 1/3}, {1/3, 0, 10/3, 0}, {0, 1/3, 0, 
    10/3}};

val = First /@ Eigensystem[{B, A}, 1];
```

All of the values are real

```
valR = val // RootReduce
```

[image]

```
Element[valR, Reals]

(* True *)

valR // N

(* {8.33542, {0.0311157, -0.179391, 0.00719285, 1.}} *)
```

However, if represented using radicals, they must use complex numbers (see [`Casus irreducibilis`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis))

```
valR // ToRadicals
```

[image]

Comment: aha, RootReduce was the magic keyword!

Answer (score 5):

```
Chop[N[First /@ Eigensystem[{B, A}, 1]]]
```

returns

```
{8.33542,{0.0311157,-0.179391,0.00719285,1.}}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure the imaginary part is exactly 0, or just close to 0, so was trying to use Mathematica to confirm my expectation

Comment: `N[First /@ Eigensystem[{B, A}, 1],256]` tries to give you the first 256 digits of each number and that shows if there is an imaginary part that it is preceded by about 256 zeros.

Answer (score 4):

This takes a long while, but it works if you just want to prove that the imaginary part is $0$.

```
B = {{17/3, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3}, {1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3}, {1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 1/
    3}, {1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 82/3}};
A = {{5/3, 0, 1/3, 0}, {0, 5/3, 0, 1/3}, {1/3, 0, 10/3, 0}, {0, 1/3, 
    0, 10/3}};
result = First /@ Eigensystem[{B, A}, 1]

Im[result] // FullSimplify
(*{0,{0,0,0,0}}*)
```

I let the computer run overnight to get the answer.  `Simplify` did not get there.

Comment: I'm eagerly waiting for computers to get fast enough for FullSimplify to run faster than overnight

Comment: `FullSimplify@Im@Numerator@Together@ComplexExpand@result` will wrap up before you can fall asleep ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try numerical evaluation with Mathematica's N[]

```
B = {{17/3, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3}, {1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3}, {1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 
1/3}, {1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 82/3}};
A = {{5/3, 0, 1/3, 0}, {0, 5/3, 0, 1/3}, {1/3, 0, 10/3, 0}, {0, 1/3, 
0, 10/3}};
First /@ Eigensystem[{N@B, N@A}, 1]
```

The result should be

```
{8.33542, {0.0306117, -0.176485, 0.00707634, 0.983802}}
```

Comment: interesting, it seems applying N before Eigenvalues is better than applying N after

Answer (score 2):

To piggyback off Bill's answer, one can just use `CountRoots[]` on the characteristic polynomial of the given matrix pencil, if one only wishes to show that the eigenvalues are all real:

```
CountRoots[CharacteristicPolynomial[{B, A}, x], x]
   4
```

One can then use `RootIntervals[]` to find brackets for the roots:

```
RootIntervals[CharacteristicPolynomial[{B, A}, x], Reals]
   {{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {3, 4}, {4, 10}}, {{1}, {1}, {1}, {1}}}
```

Note that the root at $x=0$ was exactly isolated. The largest eigenvalue of the pencil would correspond to the last entry with the isolating interval $(4,10)$, which you can then give to `Solve[]`:

```
Solve[CharacteristicPolynomial[{B, A}, x] == 0 && 4 < x < 10, x, 
      Cubics -> False, Quartics -> False]
   {{x -> Root[-19440 + 76898 #1 - 28959 #1^2 + 2401 #1^3 &, 3]}}
```

Bob has already mentioned *casus irreducibilis*; to summarize, if you insist on a radical representation, then the use of a complex representation is (often) unavoidable, even if all the roots are real.